# godot 3.5.1 going from walking to running by double tapping the movement keys doesn't seem to work

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

this is the 3D character controller for third person player game in godot, I'm trying to make it so that the player can run either by pressing SHIFT  or by double tapping the movement keys

below the script I'm using with comments, SHIFT  seems to work but but double tapping doesn't, no matter how  much I increase the timing viability

I tried this script and increasing the timer for double tap, modified the engine's maximum FPS thinking it had something to do with that, but it didn't fix the problem.

```
extends KinematicBody

export var walk_speed = 5.0  # Speed of the character's movement when walking
export var run_speed = 10.0  # Speed of the character's movement when running
export var sprint_speed = 20.0 # Speed of the character's movement when sprinting
export var gravity = 9.8  # Gravity affecting the character's vertical movement
export var jump_power = 5.0  # Power of the character's jump
export var run_key = "run"  # Key to use for running
export var weight = 1

var velocity = Vector3.ZERO  # Velocity vector of the character's movement
var is_running = false  # Whether the character is currently running
var is_double_tapping = false # Whether the player is double-tapping to sprint
var double_tap_time = 0.5 # Time frame for double-tapping (in seconds)
var double_tap_timer = 1 # Timer for tracking double-tap time
var jumping = false # Whether the player is currently jumping

func _physics_process(delta):
    # Get the input from the player
    var move_dir = Vector3.ZERO
    var cam_transform = get_node("Camroot/Camera").global_transform
    var forward = -cam_transform.basis.z
    var right = cam_transform.basis.x
    move_dir = Input.get_action_strength("move_forward") * forward - Input.get_action_strength("move_back") * forward + Input.get_action_strength("move_right") * right - Input.get_action_strength("move_left") * right
    move_dir = move_dir.normalized()

    # Update the velocity based on the input and speed, taking into account the character's orientation and whether they are running
    var target_speed = walk_speed
    if is_running:
        target_speed = run_speed
    if is_double_tapping:
        target_speed = sprint_speed
    velocity.x = move_dir.x * target_speed
    velocity.z = move_dir.z * target_speed

    # Apply gravity only if the character is not on the ground or on a slope
    if not is_on_floor() or abs(floor(get_floor_normal().dot(Vector3.UP)) - 1) > 0.001:
        velocity.y -= gravity *weight* delta

    # Jump only if the character is on the ground
    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump"):
            jumping = true

    # Update the velocity based on whether the character is jumping
    if jumping:
        velocity.y = jump_power
        jumping = false

    # Check if the run key has been pressed or released, and update the running state accordingly
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed(run_key):
        is_running = true
        if not is_double_tapping:
            is_double_tapping = true
            double_tap_timer = double_tap_time
        else:
            is_double_tapping = false
            target_speed = sprint_speed
    elif Input.is_action_just_released(run_key):
        is_running = false

    # Check if the player is double-tapping to sprint
    if is_double_tapping:
        double_tap_timer -= delta
        if double_tap_timer < 0.0:
            is_double_tapping = false

    # Move the character
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is the mechanism you want to trigger:

```
    var target_speed = walk_speed
    if is_running:
        target_speed = run_speed
    if is_double_tapping:
        target_speed = sprint_speed
```

So let us see how `is_double_tapping` becomes `true`. That would be here:

```
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed(run_key):
        is_running = true
        if not is_double_tapping:
            is_double_tapping = true
            double_tap_timer = double_tap_time
        else:
            is_double_tapping = false
            target_speed = sprint_speed
    elif Input.is_action_just_released(run_key):
        is_running = false
```

So, to `is_double_tapping` to become `true`, the player first needs to press the `run_key` action.

That is not what you said you want. You said *either*:

> I'm trying to make it so that the player can run ***either*** by pressing SHIFT or by double tapping the movement keys

But you have one mechanism gating the other. In fact, you have defined three speeds.

---

Also, you seem to interpret `is_double_tapping` in two different ways. Sometimes it means that that the time to double tap is active, sometimes it seems to mean the character should be going faster because the player double tapped. And these can't work together, because when the time to double tap ends (and `is_double_tapping` becomes `false`) you want the character to go fast if the player did double tap (with the change of speed happening when `is_double_tapping` is `true`).

And please notice that you are not checking if the player did double tap at all. Where is the code that checks if the player pressed the directions within the given time? It isn't there.

---

So, let us rethink this.

You need a timer solution. I'll keep the one you have. On the first input you start it. So you can check if the next input is within the appropriate time.

Thus, you should set `double_tap_timer` when the player pressed the direction…

That is, you should set `double_tap_timer` when `move_dir` became different from zero. *Which is something you are not checking*.

I'll pseudo-code it first:

- If `move_dir` is not zero *but was zero before*:

  - If `is_double_tapping` *and the direction is roughly the same as the old one*:

    - Increase speed.
  - If not `is_double_tapping`:

    - `is_double_tapping = true`.
    - Start double tap time.

Right, I need to have some `old_move_dir`:

- If `move_dir` is not zero and `old_move_dir` is zero:

  - If `is_double_tapping` and `move_dir.dot(old_move_dir) > 0.0`:

    - Increase speed.
  - If not `is_double_tapping`:

    - Start double tap time.
    - `is_double_tapping = true`
- `old_move_dir = move_dir`

Having three speeds will throw a wrench on it. So you have two reasons to increase speed: The player double tapped, or the player used the `run_key` action. My intuition would be to keep track of these as bool variables, and depending on them decide `target_speed`.

But when do you set them to `false`? For the `run_key` action that is easy: it ends when the player released the `run_key` action. But there is no clear end for the double tap. Surely you want to set it to `false` when the player stopped. That is when `move_dir` is zero.

Ok, let us add that:

- `is_fast_because_run_key = Input.is_action_pressed(run_key)`
- If `move_dir` is zero:

  - `is_fast_because_double_tap = false`
- Else:

  - If `old_move_dir` is zero.

    - If `is_double_tapping` and `move_dir.dot(old_move_dir) > 0.0`:

      - `is_fast_because_double_tap = true`
    - If not `is_double_tapping`.

      - Start double tap time.
      - `is_double_tapping = true`.

I'll write that as code now:

```
is_fast_because_run_key = Input.is_action_pressed(run_key)
if move_dir.is_equal_approx(Vector3.ZERO):
    is_fast_because_double_tap = false
else:
    if old_move_dir.is_equal_approx(Vector3.ZERO):
        if is_double_tapping and move_dir.dot(old_move_dir) > 0.0:
            is_fast_because_double_tap = true
        if not is_double_tapping:
            is_double_tapping = true
            double_tap_timer = double_tap_time

old_move_dir = move_dir
```

Then you can pick `target_speed` like this:

```
if is_fast_because_run_key and is_fast_because_double_tap:
    target_speed = sprint_speed
elif is_fast_because_run_key or is_fast_because_double_tap:
    target_speed = run_speed
else:
    target_speed = walk_speed
```

You can get rid of the part where you used to check `run_key`.

And, of course, you still need this code:

```
    # Check if the player is double-tapping to sprint
    if is_double_tapping:
        double_tap_timer -= delta
        if double_tap_timer < 0.0:
            is_double_tapping = false
```